# Find probability for license plate

Tags: probability

A license plate is made of 3 letters (using the letters  − ) followed by 4 numbers (using the numbers 0 − 9). Assume that no
repetitions are allowed. Leave the answers of the following parts as simplified fractions.
(a) Assume one of the license plates is randomly picked. What is the chance the chosen license plate has an  and a 1 in it?
(b) What is the chance the license plate has either a 1 or a 2 or both?

For a., I got $$\frac{25 \cdot 24 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7}{26 \cdot 25 \cdot 24 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7}$$

b. I got $$\frac{26 \cdot 25 \cdot 24 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 + 26 \cdot 25 \cdot 24 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 - 26 \cdot 25 \cdot 24 \cdot 8 \cdot 7}{26 \cdot 25 \cdot 24 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7}$$

I feel like both of my answers check out- for a, there's only 1 choice for if there's an A in the plate, leaving 25 and 24 possibilities for the next two spots, and the same concept for the numbers. Then, you divide the result by the total possible combinations. For the second one, add the possibilities of a plate having a 1 and a plate having a 2, then subtract the repeating combinations.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  In part (a), you forgot to account for the position of the A.  Since there are three places where the A could go, you would have to multiply your answer by $3$, which would bring it into agreement with Robert Shore's answer.  Similarly, you did not take the positions of the $1$ and $2$ into account in part (b).

Answer (score 2):

It's important that no repetitions are allowed.  The probability that one of your three letters will be an A is simply $\dfrac{3}{26}$.  Any combination of three letters is equally likely, so the question is the probability of drawing a A given three chances to draw a letter from the alphabet without replacement.  Similarly, the probability that one of the four numbers will be a $1$ is $\dfrac {4}{10}=\dfrac 25$.  Therefore, the answer for part (a) is simply $\dfrac{3}{25 \cdot 13}= \dfrac{3}{325}$.

For part (b), the easier calculation is the probability that none of your $4$ numbers are $1$ or $2$.  That probability is $\dfrac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5}{10^4}= \dfrac {21}{125}$, so the probability that at least one of $1$ or $2$ is included within your numbers is $1-\dfrac{21}{125}=\dfrac {104}{125}$.